# Html Dropdown menu using page id's

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a selectbox that redirects to different pages using the page id after select. Here is what I have but it doesn't redirect. Why?

```
    <form>
 <select name="pageid" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.pageid.options[this.form.pageid.selectedIndex].value">
  <option id="">Choose a page</option>
  <option id="page19">Page 19</option>
  <option id="page18">Page 18</option>
  <option id="page8">Page 8</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post this erros? Look at Chrome/Firebug console and post it! Change the onchange="javascript:window.location.href=this.form.." too!

Comment: Adding `javascript:` to an event handler attribute does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You meant to write `<option value="...">` instead of `id="..."`.

I would advise against using this style of 'jump menu'. It has negative usability, accessibility, navigational and SEO implications. In general prefer a div full of links which can be shown/hidden.

Comment: ...and he probably wated `<option value="?id=page19">Page 19</option>`

Comment: Jan yes that is what i think i am wanting but i want the drop down to navigate through the different page ids what should the top line be<select name="pageid" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.pageid.options[this.form.pageid.selectedIndex].value">

Comment: That's a bit unnecessarily verbose - `this.form.pageid` refers to the select itself and so is the same thing as `this`, for example - but in principle it should work. (Well, as much as jump menus ever do - they're really not a good thing.)